# I have rounded progress bar, how can I fill it depending on the occupied and vacant space?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some code for rounded progress bar and a css file. If the value of the occupied space will be increase depends on that the progress bar shown a % of full or empty.

```
<div class="page">
  <h1>Pure CSS Percentage Circle - circle100</h1>
  <!-- green -->
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="c100 p50 big green"> <span>50%</span>
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put the code in your question bar in comment it looks like ugly

Comment: Please put your relative codes here https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/p7LycL23/

Comment: Appreciated...thank you krish

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guy's code - 
http://codepen.io/geedmo/pen/InFfd

***HTML :***

```
<div class="wrap">

<div class="progress-radial progress-25">
  <div class="overlay">25%</div>
</div>

<div class="progress-radial progress-50">
  <div class="overlay">50%</div>
</div>

<div class="progress-radial progress-75">
  <div class="overlay">75%</div>
</div>

<div class="progress-radial progress-90">
  <div class="overlay">90%</div>
</div>

</div>
```

***CSS :***

```
    @import compass

// Colors
$barColor: tomato
$overlayColor: #fffde8
$backColor: #2f3439

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans)

body
  padding: 30px 0
  background-color: $backColor
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif

.wrap
  width: 600px
  margin: 0 auto

/* -------------------------------------
 * Bar container
 * ------------------------------------- */
.progress-radial
  float: left
  margin-right: 30px
  position: relative
  width: 100px
  height: 100px
  border-radius: 50%
  border: 2px solid $backColor // remove gradient color
  background-color: $barColor // default 100%

/* -------------------------------------
 * Optional centered circle w/text
 * ------------------------------------- */  
.progress-radial .overlay
  position: absolute
  width: 60px
  height: 60px
  background-color: $overlayColor
  border-radius: 50%
  margin-left: 20px
  margin-top: 20px
  text-align: center
  line-height: 60px
  font-size: 16px

/* -------------------------------------
 * Mixin for progress-% class
 * ------------------------------------- */

$step: 5 // step of % for created classes

$loops: round(100 / $step)
$increment: 360 / $loops
$half: round($loops / 2)
@for $i from 0 through $loops
  .progress-#{$i*$step}
    @if $i < $half
      $nextdeg: 90deg + ( $increment * $i )
      background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $backColor 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient($nextdeg, $barColor 50%, $backColor 50%, $backColor)
    @else
      $nextdeg: -90deg + ( $increment * ( $i - $half ) )
      background-image: linear-gradient($nextdeg, $barColor 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, $barColor 50%, $backColor 50%, $backColor)
```

Comment: Yes.....i have this code also...but the problem is that...i don't know how to implement it to find a vacant and occupied space. I'll tell you the exact matter, if there are 500 spaces out of that 300 are occupied and 200 are vacant, how i shows this by using the rounded progress bar.

Comment: it sounds like what you need is more of a graph than a progress bar

maybe this will help you more ? 

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart